# Is it possible to write a java program that pop a window where user can write SQL script Code?

Tags: java, sql

i would like to know if there is a way to write a java program that pop a window where the the user can enter some SQL Script code ? the result would be save in a .SQL File.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible. Take a look on [Eclipse SQL explorer](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/). As an eclipse plugin it is written in java. As a SQL plugin it allows editing and running SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe .sql files are plain text, which removes the relevance of SQL specifically. 
You could just develop a simple application with a UI displaying a text area and "save"/"cancel" buttons, wherein on save, a new file is created and named [something].sql, with the text from the text area. 
Up to you then, to improve the application and actually validate the SQL in the text area before allowing the user to save.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter
                            (new File("schema.sql"));

        String SQL = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                ("Enter your SQL code: ");

        SQL = SQL + "\n";

        out.write(SQL);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```